# SQL Pivot without aggregation

Tags: sql-server, pivot, max, aggregation

I have a Problem converting rows in columns of a SQL Result.

My structure is like this:

GUID | PropertyName | PropertyValue

abcd | DistinguishedName | cn=abcd...

abcd| CN               |  cn= GROUP_

abcd| Operation        | ADD

1231 | DistinguishedName| cn=123dd

1231 | Cn               | cn=ASDGRUOP

1231 | Operation        | DEL

There can be n PropertyNames that I dont know before, they are dynamically - i can get them through an SQL, that is not the Problem.

I want to have a structure like this:
GUID | DistinguishedName | CN  | Operation

abcd| cn=abcd...| cn= GROUP_ | ADD

1231 | cn=123dd | cn=ADSGROUP | DEL

and so on.

The Column-Headers i get by this SQL:

```
select @cols = STUFF (( SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + x.ParameterName  from ... and parametername in ('PropertyValue','DistinguishedName', 'Operation')
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') + ']'
```

I can do this with PIVOT-Function but because i dont have Aggregation, I cant get the right result:

```
set @query = N'SELECT '+ @cols + ' FROM (
    SELECT x.parametervalue, x.parametername
    from ... and parametername in (''PropertyValue'',''DistinguishedName'', ''Operation'')
    ) a
    PIVOT (max(a.parametervalue) FOR ParameterName in ( ' + @cols + ')) as pv;' 
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

I get the following result:

GUID | DistinguishedName | CN | Operation | ... other Propertys

abcd | cn=abcd...           | cn = GROUP_ |ADD |...

Only 1 Result - not more. But there are like 700 Results from this query, because of the MAX() function i get only one. How can I get a Pivot without Aggregation to get all of the results?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: It's difficult to help out without having a *complete* example. You're close. You just need to make sure that the *resultset* that you're pivoting does include the `GUID` column as well as each of the `parameter` columns, since a `PIVOT` operation always produces one row *per* distinct set of values for the columns in the result set that *aren't* part of the `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the dynamic `PIVOT` query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @cols NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = 
    STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(PropertyName) 
        FROM #tbl
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    , 1, 1, '')

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT GUID, ' + @cols + '
FROM (
    SELECT
        GUID, PropertyName, PropertyValue
    FROM #tbl
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(PropertyValue)
    FOR PropertyName IN(' + @cols + ')
) p ';

PRINT (@sql);
EXEC (@sql);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/500293)</kbd>

---

Another way to achieve the desired result is to use a [dynamic crosstab](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT
    GUID' + CHAR(10) +
(SELECT DISTINCT
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN PropertyName = ''' + PropertyName + ''' THEN PropertyValue END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(PropertyName) + CHAR(10)
FROM #tbl
FOR XML PATH('')
) +
'FROM #tbl
GROUP BY GUID;';

PRINT (@sql);
EXEC (@sql);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/500289)</kbd>

Comment: ist Working! Thank you very much for the fast and brilliant answer!

Comment: The Only Problem is, i must execute this SQL within a Report-Editor and this program doesnt know the command EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL. How can I transform the query so that it runs without this command?